# Fill null values with next non-null value bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table with data from GA in BigQuery

```
userid  visitid purchase_date
GH8932  12345   2017-04-09
GH8932  12346   null
GH8932  12347   null
GH8932  12348   null
GH8932  12349   2017-05-30
GH8932  12350   null
GH8932  12351   null
GH8932  12352   2017-06-07
GH8932  12353   null
GH8932  12354   2017-06-30
```

And I want the resulting table to be

```
userid  visitid purchase_date
GH8932  12345   2017-04-09
GH8932  12346   2017-05-30
GH8932  12347   2017-05-30
GH8932  12348   2017-05-30
GH8932  12349   2017-05-30
GH8932  12350   2017-06-07
GH8932  12351   2017-06-07
GH8932  12352   2017-06-07
GH8932  12353   2017-06-30
GH8932  12354   2017-06-30
```

I tried the following

```
select
a.userid,
a.visitid,
b.purchase_date
from x
left join
( 
select 
userid,
visitid,
purchase_data 
from x 
where purchase_date is not null) as b
on x.userid = b.userid
where x.visitid <= b.visitid
```

But, this doesn't provide the solution I'm looking for.

Appreciate the help for a BQ rookie

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use IGNORE NULLS with FIRST_VALUE to find a non null date in the desired window:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  visitid,
  FIRST_VALUE(purchase_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY visitid
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND
    UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS purchase_date
FROM x;
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliot Brossard, I just realized that there are a few more 'nulls' after the final visit, which needs to be overwritten with the final 'purchase_date'. Any way we can achieve this?

Comment: Can you maybe post a separate question? That way you'll get input on a solution from other people as well.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. Thanks